# tsc not found after running docker image build

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker

I want to deploy this program on local host. when i am doing manually "npm run build-tsc" it is working. But i want that when i will run docker image build, it will be automatically run by docker. But it is saying tsc is not found. I have already installed tsc globally.
**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV=production


WORKDIR /src/server.ts
COPY ["package.json", "npm-shrinkwrap.json*", "./"]
RUN npm install --production --silent &&  mv node_modules ../

COPY . .
EXPOSE 8000
RUN npm ci
RUN npm run build-tsc
RUN chown -R node /dist/server.js
USER node
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "university-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "this is an university management application",
  "main": "src/server.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only src/server.ts",
    "start": "node dist/server.js",
    "lint:check": "eslint --ignore-path .eslintignore --ext .js,.ts .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --fix",
    "prettier:check": "prettier --ignore-path .gitignore --write \"**/*.+(js|ts|json)\"",
    "prettier:fix": "prettier --write .",
    "lint-prettier": "yarn lint:check && yarn prettier:check",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build-tsc": "tsc"
  },
  "author": "Adil Mahmoud Rion",
  "license": "ISC",
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.ts": "yarn lint-prettier"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.13",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.60.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.60.1",
    "eslint": "^8.43.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "lint-staged": "^13.2.3",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "http-status": "^1.6.2",
    "mongoose": "^7.3.1",
    "zod": "^3.21.4",
    "typescript": "^5.1.5"
  }
}
```

Error:
[image]

I am expecting that when i will build docker image, the tsc command will auto run by docker.
I have already deleted package-lock.json, but the problem is not fixed.

Comment: You asked npm to install for production, skipping dev dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You install typescript as `devDependencies` and as `dependencies`. Remove it from `devDependencies` and keep in `dependencies`. Because you run npm install with --production flag. It see typescript module in devDependencies and ignore it - according to --production flag. Or remove --production flag. [See this doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install)